# Method over Boolean array should return true if any value in the array is true

Tags: ruby, boolean-operations

This code works very well:

```
def is_rel_prime?(*args)                              #1
  test = args.combination(2).to_a                     #2
  test.map! { |a,b| a == Rational(a,b).numerator }    #3
  test.reduce (:&)                                    #4
end

> is_rel_prime?(3,4,5) #=> true
> is_rel_prime?(7,12,14) #=> false
> is_rel_prime?(7,12,15) #=> false
```

What do I replace the (:&) with so that it will return 'true' if ANY ONE (or more) of the array elements is 'true'?

Comment: Change the last line to `test.any?` or drop that line and change `test.map!...` to: `test.map { |a,b| a == Rational(a,b).numerator }.any?` (no need for !). `test.any?` returns `true` if any element of `test` is "thruthy" (neither `nil` nor `false`); else returns `false`.

Comment: `args.combination(2).any? { |a,b| a == Rational(a,b).numerator }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code there is testing `bool & bool & bool`. `Boolean#&` is equivalent to `&&` in general usage. As you might suspect, the corollary here is `Boolean#|`, which is equivalent to `||` in general usage. So, in your code, you would use `test.reduce(:|)` to decide if any boolean in the list is true.

That said, Cary is correct in that Ruby already has facilities for checking the truthiness of any value in an enumerable, via `Enumerable#any?` (and can check the truthiness of all values via `Enumerable#all?`), so you should just use those rather than rolling your own checker.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `:&` with `:|` (Boolean AND with Boolean OR).